# error cannot create a folder folder_name? in git

Tags: git-bash

My git is not working properly.when i try to pull from the repository I get the following error

> fatal error cannot create a folder project/abc/abc/abc/abc/abc...

when i try to push also I'm getting the same error.I cannot even merge.

```
git pull
fatal error:cannot create the directory project/abc/abc/abc/abc/abc...

git push
fatal error:cannot create the directory project/abc/abc/abc/abc/abc...
```

what is happening behind the screens?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try git pull from the root. You might not have permissions.

If you dont have the root enabled, you enable it.

Refer http://www.ducea.com/2006/06/21/ubuntu-how-to-enable-the-root-account/

Comment: Thanks it worked.I didnt have permissions so that is why it was giving error.Now it is working.